# Map annotations won't show in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I'm using the following code to add annotations to a mapView. The problem is that the annotations don't appear in iOS 7 but do show up in iOS6

in my `viewDidLoad` method:

```
for (int i=0; i<[self.listingNodesArray count]; i++) {
    MyAnnotation* annotation= [MyAnnotation new];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    coordinate.latitude = [[[[self.listingNodesArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"address"] objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
    coordinate.longitude = [[[[self.listingNodesArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"address"] objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue];

    annView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PIN_img.png"];// sets image for pin

    annotation.coordinate = coordinate;

    annotation.title = [[self.listingNodesArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"title"];
    annotation.subtitle = [[[self.listingNodesArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"address"] objectForKey:@"address"];

    NSNumber *listingIdNumber = [[self.listingNodesArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];

    annotation.catListingMapId = listingIdNumber;

    [self.topMapView addAnnotation: annotation];

}

[self.view addSubview:self.topMapView];
```

and `viewForAnnotation`:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapingView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation {
    annView = nil;
    if(annotation != mapingView.userLocation)
    {

        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"";
        annView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapingView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        if ( annView == nil )
            annView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]
                       initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] ;


        UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //   [rightButton addTarget:self
        //               action:@selector(showDetails:)
        //   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

        annView.canShowCallout = YES;

    }

    return annView;
}
```

and my annotation file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapViewAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {

    NSString *title;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d;

@end

    #import "MapViewAnnotation.h"

@implementation MapViewAnnotation

@synthesize title, coordinate;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d {

    title = ttl;
    coordinate = c2d;
    return self;
}


@end
```

Comment: Don't set `annView.image` _outside_ the viewForAnnotation method.  Set it _inside_ the delegate method along with the setting the accessory view.  If it "works" in iOS 6 that's just by chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As AnnaKarenina points out, you should set the `image` of your annotation view inside the `viewForAnnotation` method.

This may be somewhat "working" in iOS 6, but surely not completely. You're trying to set the annotation view's `image` before the annotation has been added to the map (and, thus, before the annotation view for this annotation has even been created). At best, you're setting the annotation view `image` for the prior annotation, not the one you think you are.

If your various annotations need to have unique images, go ahead and add a `imageName` property to your annotation, and then you can have your `viewForAnnotation` set the annotation view's image using that property. That's where you should be creating the `UIImage` for the annotation view. Frankly, I'd suggest you remove the `annView` ivar, to avoid the temptation to try to access the annotation view outside of `viewForAnnotation`.

By the way, the `MapViewAnnotation` class (referred to elsewhere as `MyAnnotation`) has lots of little issues of its own (e.g. your `init` is not calling `super`, you've defined the strings to be `copy` parameters but `init` is not doing that (such as `title = [ttl copy]`), its now advised that you don't explicitly create the ivars that back your properties, etc.), but those are unrelated to the broader issues regarding your annotation view images.